# Fonts are not included when printing into PDF using QT on linux

Tags: linux, qt, pdf, fonts

On Linux, when I use Qt to print in PDF format, the fonts are not included in the document (okular says no fonts) and then the text is a graphic and the letters are not sharp.

Qtconfig says that the setting is to embed fonts in the document.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Are the font embeddable at all? You may have to test that with software where you positively know that it does embed (and subset) the fonts.

Comment: this is a bug many people are having on linux https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52417